# How to get data at side menu ionic 4

Tags: ionic4

I am using ionic 4. I want to ask if I want to send value to side menu then when I open the menu the value is already at side menu. Now I need to open the side menu then click one time to show the value. Can I know how to do it? Here is my code. Thank you

**app.component.html**

```
<ion-menu side="start" (click)="onOpen()">
    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-menu-toggle>
          <ion-item lines="none">
            <ion-icon name="business" slot="start"></ion-icon>
            <ion-label>{‌{text}}</ion-label>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-menu-toggle>
          </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-menu>
  <ion-router-outlet main></ion-router-outlet>
</ion-app>
```

I put the onOpen() method at **app.component.ts**

```
onOpen() {
    this.text = "my pass value";
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want something triggered when the menu is opened you need to handle the `ionWillOpen` or `ionDidOpen` events:

- [ion-menu - Ionic Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/menu#events)

An example of this would look like:

```
<ion-menu (ionWillOpen)="onMenuOpen()" (ionDidOpen)="menuOpened()">
```

Comment: Thank you very much